# Android Worker Thread for HTTP Requests

Tags: android, http, queue

I have a worker thread that runs in an infinite loop. If it's queue of http requests is empty it waits. As soon as a http request is added to the queue it gets notified and executes this http request. This works all fine but I have some questions on this:

I'm doing it something like this (shortened!):

```
mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
mHttpPost = new HttpPost(MyHttpClient.getAbsoluteUrl(url);

while (true)
{
    // Check if the queue is empty, if so -> wait
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(queue.poll());       
    mHttpPost.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpPost);
}
```

The question is: is this the most efficient way to do it if the queue has like 100 items? Does the http connection remain open all the time or does it get connected again and again? And if it remains open, is it a good idea to leave it open all the time when the app is running, or should I close it until new items are added to the queue?

The second question is concerning the infinite loop. I need the thread to run all the time when the app is running but the still the infinite loop doesn't look nice. I know I could make something like: while(!cancelled) but I don't call a thread.cancel() method anyway because I mean there is no App.onDestroy() event where I could call thread.cancel(), right? How would you handle that? Because I'd actually want to save the queue to "disk" when the thread is killed by the system but how can this be done?

Sorry for the long text and my bad english